# Load html from assets folder and add query parameters with webview_flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I want to send query parameters to my HTML in the assets folder with the webview_flutter package.

I added the HTML file to my pubspec.yaml file.

This is my code.

```
//Dart
import 'dart:convert';
//flutter
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//plugins
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() {
    return HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Help')),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'about:blank',
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;
          _loadHtmlFromAssets();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/web/index.html');
    _controller.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileText,
            mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
        .toString());
  }
}
```

I tried to add parameters like this. but it can't load HTML.

```
_loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileText = await rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/web/index.html?url=https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4');
    _controller.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileText,
            mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
        .toString());
  }
```

I also thoughts about the JavaScript the javascriptChannels it can send data from java script to the dart file. but I have no idea how to send data from dart file to html file with the web view?

Comment: Any update on this query?

Comment: any solution for this query param?

Comment: Any solution for this?